# JSONP Cross Domain Data

Tags: php, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I've been trying for several hours now all the examples that I could find on google and none work for me. All I want is to have 2 files, an HTML one and a PHP one, each on a separate server. I'd like the HTML file to be able to access some information from the PHP page which I can then use inside the HTML file in an alert(); function for example.

I just need a really basic, dummy proof example that says "put this code in the HTML file and put this code in the PHP file".

To show you an example I've tried the following article: http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/

This is where I put the server side code: http://3d-sign.com/wip/recoup/database_2.php
This is where I put the client side code (from example 1): http://3d-sign.com/wip/recoup/read_test.php

(I know I will need these files on separate servers but if they work on separate, they should also work on the same server too, right?)

Please help me :(

Comment: check your server for `CROSS blocked`.

Comment: your `database_2.php` shows warning.

Comment: What is the need of `JSONP` If both are on same server with same domain and ports.

Comment: Jai they're both on the same server atm just for testing. I'll look into the other 2 matters shortly. Thanks!